# Can I repair corrupted windows 10 by running DISM or SFC but over the web using SSH?

Tags: windows-10, remote-access, ssh-tunnel, repair, bootrepair

Assuming the windows 10 system had all the files and programs ready to accept remote access via SSH (a guide or a small step by step reference would help) and also assuming that all access codes and usernames are available to me, is there a change for it to be fixed if the computer starts but for some reason does not finish the boot into the home screen?

like for example could I SSH into the machine and run a DISM or SFC command? (assuming that the PC is not completely briged and that its a higher lvl issue like driver conflict or something like that )

Comment: Are the required services for remote access loaded?

Comment: I am not seeking a yes, no answer I am seeking for an explanation as to how to achieve the above so if you know and would like to help mention the services that need to be installed the commands to run and whatever else is needed or share links with resources as to how to achieve that. Thank you.

Comment: I asked because it's a requirement. If you want to remotely repair it at least the services needed for such remote access have to be running. There's no way to remotely activate a remote access, obviously, as that would be a major security flaw.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Why would it be a security flaw? SSH connections need a secure SHA256 key that only the 2 terminals share with each other + you need to know ip,port,username,password.

Comment: The point isn't about ssh being insecure - it isn't - the point is about *There's no way to remotely activate a remote access*, meaning if the server isn't running and configured for ssh you won't be able to remotely do that.

Comment: Oh that was what you meant? Yea sure, but I am asking for guidance on how to set up e.g PC1 so that I can remotely (over the internet from e.g PC2) access it via SSH and run for example some command prompt commands on it like SFC